# Como podria configurar esta route de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, router

antes que nada, doy gracias de antemano por entrar a este post, no soy desarrollador backend ni manejo PHP, pero por cosas del destino necesito acomodar un link (a tag) y el proyecto esta desarrollado en Laravel.

La route no esta configurada, así que fui a web.php y coloque lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('recover', function(){return view('/auth/passwords/verify');})->name('recover');
```

Luego fui a la view de login y coloque esta ancla

```
<a href="/recover">Forgot your password? click here</a>
```

Luego pruebo el enlace en la pagina de login y me da el siguiente error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [.auth.passwords.verify] not found.
```

[image: Imagen del error]

De verdad agradezco su ayuda, no soy experto en backend, apenas manejo lo basico de PHP, saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Para acceder a las vistas debes usar el punto (.). Por ende, tu acceso a la vista debería ser así: `view('auth.passwords.verify')`

Comment: @L.Flor cierto es pero también funciona con /

Comment: @vanegranda seguro que los nombres y ubicación de esa vista están correctos? no tendrás el detalle con alguna mayúscula o así?

Comment: Si tienes acceso al proyecto (codigo fuente) puedes ir a la ruta del proyecto, y en tu consola ejecutar el siguiente comando `php artisan route:list` para ver si tienes esa ruta predefinida o, es una ruta nueva.

Comment: @BetaM Hasta donde yo he visto, las rutas estan correctas, la pagina de login se encuentra en `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` y la pagina de Verify a la que quiero digirir el ancla esta en `resources/views/auth/passwords/verify.blade.php`

Comment: @L.Flor Probe con usar los puntos pero me sigue dando el mismo error, muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Cuando cambiaste a puntos... dejaste es slash inicial? O lo cambiaste por algun punto, no debes iniciar mas que con la carpeta de origin, es decir, no debe llevar punto ni slash